# Does Atavism give more bonuses on top of the Advanced template, or is it just summarizing?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, character-templates

From Druid 4th level spell Atavism:

> The animal immediately gains the advanced creature simple template. It gains a +2 bonus on all rolls, including damage rolls and special ability DCs, a +4 bonus to AC and CMD, and +2 hit points per HD.

Is the second sentence simply a summary of the benefits of the Advanced template, or additional benefits applied on top of the Advanced Template?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While an argument can be made for the [*atavism*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/atavism/) spell as written allowing the stacking of the benefits from *both* the spell's description *and* the template the spell grants, this reader has several reasons for viewing the *atavism* spell as, instead, trying to be helpful by providing in its description a summary of the [advanced template](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/advanced-creature-cr-1).

First, the spell's description says that the subject "gains a +2 bonus on all rolls, including damage rolls and special ability DCs, a +4 bonus to AC and CMD, and +2 hit points per HD," while the advanced template says that a creature to which it has been applied gain a "+2 on all rolls (including damage rolls) and special ability DCs; +4 to AC and CMD; +2 hp/HD," making these two descriptions nearly identical. While not *utterly* absurd, essentially *doubling* the advanced template's benefits is *a lot* of oomph, even for a 4th-level spell.

Second, often when a spell provides an extra benefit the spell description makes that extra benefit obvious by using terms like *also* as in the spells [*restoration*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/restoration/) and [*spirit-bound blade*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/spirit-bound-blade/) or *further* as in the spells [*ironwood*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/ironwood/) and [*true seeing*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/true-seeing/). Such a term is absent in that sentence that could be detailing the the *atavism* spell's extra benefits.

Finally, the *atavism* spell "has no effect on animals that already have the advanced creature template," so it would be a strange spell indeed for it to forbid an already advanced creature from gaining *greater* bonuses because it can't be granted *lesser* bonuses.

Combined, while a case can be made for the contrary, this GM would rule that the spell only applies the advanced template not the advanced template *and* the benefits the described in the spell. This ruling also appears to jibe with this [2015 Paizo messageboard thread](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2sfz8?Atavism-spell-make-animal-companions) that describes the spell's use in a Pathfinder Society scenario.